# Reducing "noise" in spatially regressed points

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, regression, autocorrelation

I'm working on spatial data on a grid. I have two variables that I think to be correlated and I would like to build a model (see Fig attached)[image].

I did some exploratory analyses following the instructions in the spdep R package and I found (as expected) spatial autocorrelation in the residuals of the classical linear regression (OSL) between these two variables.

I used the Spatial Autoregressive Model to estimate the parameters of the spatial regression.

I suppose that the noise seen in the Fig attached is partially due to spatial autocorrelation in the data.
I would like to plot my data taking in account spatial autocorrelation of the residuals, in other words I would like to reduce the "noise" across observation, so that the values fit more to the regressed line.

Would be this possible? Does it make sense my reasoning? I'm quite new to spatial statistics and I would like to learn more.

Comment: I've come back to this Q a few times and I'm still not clear. The noise in the plot is the noise in the data. "I would like to plot my data taking in account spatial autocorrelation of the residuals" - doesn't make much sense - if you somehow take into account the SA then you're not plotting the data. Is the plot you want a map or a 1-d plot of something against something else? And finally something I ask of all graphics: "What is the question that this plot is going to answer?"

Comment: The question is if it exists a correlation between these two variables, accounting for the probable presence of spatial autocorrelation. Statistically, I know that there is a significant correlation (after the SAR test). Now, I'm wondering whether the residuals that i see in the plot (that is the difference between the observed data and the fitted line) could be reduced. Assuming that the diff between the observed data and the fitted line is partially due to spatial autocorrelation. I would assume also that "noise" is also due to the stochastic process from which the data have been extracted.

Comment: Most spatial regression models have a linear component, a spatial component, and an error component: `Y = XB + S(s) + e` and they differ in how you model `S(s)` and its covariance. I *think* you want to subtract `S(s)`, the spatial component, from your predictions. How you get that from your fitted model depends on your code, which you've not given us. Also there's no guarantee this will reduce the noise in a plot, it could even make it worse. What are you trying to do with this procedure?

Comment: My reasoning is based on a "speculation", which I do not know whether is correct or not. That is, the plot shows deviations between observed values and expected values (regressed line). I may explain this lack of perfect fit as due to statistic drift and/or to the fact that data are spatially autocorrelated. The reason why I said "spatially auto corr data" is because I would expect that observed data values can be affected by the geographic surroundings. Is it a bit more clear?

Comment: Is your plot of the linear (non-spatial) model fit? If so, could you not just plot the residuals from your spatial model? The residuals should be smaller because you've accounted for spatial autocorrelation

Comment: Yes, the plot is of linear non-spatial fit. And yes, I plotted the residuals, but I was wondering whether would be possible to "transform" my data by reducing the "statistical nuisance" on them and re-do the linear plot. I would expect with the "transformed" data, a closer fit to the estimated line.